# What is the status of this transaction?

Tags: jaxx

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfed520a57c874af9dbddc8fd0e7a470f738c45ad4432266fee8f0e18df50e0de

It says the status is false.

I sent money from my jaxx wallet to poloniex. Poloniex do not credit the fund.

It seems that Jaxx took 1 eth out of my wallet.

So what's actually the status?

Do I lost 1 eth?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The transaction failed, so the ETH never left your wallet. It's still in your wallet if you check your address [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x09af42e584242cffe3cfeafc1c3fb4be69c9be87). If it still doesn't show up, then that must be a bug in Jaxx. You'll have to contact their support for further help.